# Return document if only sub-document elements matched within a nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation

The main collection is **User**, and we have a **User profile** collection which having experience details and other stuff. Also, we have a **Skill** collection.

**USER**

```
[{
    "_id": "5f1eef8ec68d306fbbf13b0f",
    "name": "John Davis",
    "email": "John@gmail.com",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "9q1eef8ec68d306fbbf13bh6",
    "name": "Mik Luca",
    "email": "Mik@gmail.com",
    "__v": 0
}]
```

**User profile**

```
[{
        "_id": "5f1eef8ec68d306fbbf13b10",
        "other_skills": [
            null
        ],
        "user_id": "5f1eef8ec68d306fbbf13b0f",
        "phone_number": "1234569870",
        "location": "5f16b72617fee02922688751",
        "primary_skills": [
            {
                "_id": "5f32635cf764cc40447503a6",
                "years": 1,
                "skill_id": "5f0da75907a96c3040b3667d"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f1eef8ec68d306fbbf13b10",
        "other_skills": [
            null
        ],
        "user_id": "9q1eef8ec68d306fbbf13bh6",
        "phone_number": "1234569870",
        "location": "5f16b72617fee02922688751",
        "primary_skills": [
            {
                "_id": "6s0da75907a96c3040b36690",
                "years": 1,
                "skill_id": "5f0da75907a96c3040b3667d"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

**Skill**

```
[{  
    "_id": "5f0da75907a96c3040b3667d",
    "skill": "Mongo"
},
{  
    "_id": "6s0da75907a96c3040b36690",
    "skill": "Node"
}]
```

I need to list the users with their user profile info and need to filter with skills as well

I have tried

```
db.getCollection("users").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "_id" : NumberInt(0), 
                "users" : "$$ROOT"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "localField" : "users._id", 
                "from" : "userprofiles", 
                "foreignField" : "user_id", 
                "as" : "userprofiles"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$userprofiles", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "localField" : "userprofiles.primary_skills.skill_id", 
                "from" : "skills", 
                "foreignField" : "_id", 
                "as" : "skills"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$skills", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "skills._id" : ObjectId("5f0dce8d07a96c3040b36687")
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
);
```

But not getting the proper results.

How can I populate the **user profile** and **skill** information with the **User** list and filter the user list with Skill ids?

Greetings and thanks.

Comment: Please post your expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match filters inside lookup using lookup with pipeline,

- `$lookup` with `userProfile` collection
- pipelines `$match` to match profile id
- other filters for profile like `skill_id` match here
- `$unwind` deconstruct `primary_skills` array because we are going to lookup with skill_id
- `$lookup` will `skills` collection
- `$unwind` deconstruct `primary_skills.skill_id` array because we need it as object
- `$grpup` reconstruct `primary_skills` array
- `$match` if `userProfiles` not equal to empty `[]`

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "usersProfile",
      let: { id: "$_id" },
      as: "userProfiles",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: { 
             $expr: { $eq: ["$$id", "$user_id"] },
             // match here user profile filters
            "primary_skills.skill_id": "5f0da75907a96c3040b3667d"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$primary_skills" },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "skills",
            localField: "primary_skills.skill_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "primary_skills.skill_id"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$primary_skills.skill_id" },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            other_skills: { $first: "$other_skills" },
            phone_number: { $first: "$phone_number" },
            location: { $first: "$location" },
            primary_skills: {
              $push: {
                _id: "$primary_skills._id",
                skill: "$primary_skills.skill_id.skill",
                years: "$primary_skills.years"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $match: { userProfiles: { $ne: [] } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9r1okoW1jdR)

Comment: Thanks, @turivishal for the answer. After applying some tweaks, it's working in my use case.